# How to solve #1064 error in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I got MySQL syntax Error 1064 while I am add new column.

```
ALTER TABLE `customerdetails` ADD `mobile` DOUBLE(12) NOT NULL ;
```

where `customerdetails` is the name of the table.

The Error message is " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL' at line 1

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Show the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are defining column type as `DOUBLE` you have to define how many decimal places it will use

```
ALTER TABLE customerdetails ADD mobile DOUBLE(12,2) NOT NULL ;
```

Also first number (Characteristic) needs to be bigger than second number (Mantissa)